# Best practice for Phalcon model relationship

Tags: phalcon

Loving working with Phalcon, but have concerns about the best practice for model relationships. For example, if I have the following db relationship:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/smo6C.png

And create a relationship in the Thing model like:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasOne('categoryId', 'Categories', 'id', array('alias' => 'cat'));
}
```

The following easily prints off beautifully:

```
{{ thing.cat.name }}
```

Whereas pre-phalcon I would join the 2 to make 1 round trip, the elegance is worth the 2 DB hits...

... until you are grabbing a list of say 1,000 Things and looping through like:

```
{{ for thing in things }}
    <li>{{ thing.cat.name }}</li>
{{ endfor }}
```

Then I am getting 1,001 DB calls (assuming there are 1,000 different categories I guess).

What is the best practice for dealing with this scenario? And not just for a simple relationship like this where the lookup could be fairly static and easy to cache. What about a more dynamic relationship where you may be listing invoices between historical dates, their customers and the category of the customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For building more complex queries you probably want to check those [query builder examples](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/phql.html#creating-queries-using-the-query-builder).

Essential (not tested) is:

```
$things = $this->modelsManager->createBuilder()
    ->from('Things', 'thing')
    ->leftJoin('Categories', 'category.id = thing.categoryId', 'category')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();

var_dump($things->toArray());
```

Comment: Thanks! Only note for future readers: From function accepts a string for Model, or array of Models. To alias, the format is [ alias => model ].

Answer (score 1):

Adding `'reusable' => true` may help.

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasOne('categoryId', 'Categories', 'id', array(
        'alias' => 'cat', 'reusable' => true));
}
```

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models-cache.html#reusable-related-records

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you're asking. Though if I understand correctly are you looking for something like:

```
// Thing model
public function initialize()
{
    $this->belongsTo('categoryId', 'Categories', 'id');
}

// Category model
public function initialize()
{
    $this->hasMany('id', 'Things', 'categoryId', array('alias' => 'things'));
}

// Output things in certain category
foreach($category->things as $thing)
{
    echo $thing->name;
}
```

If I have completely misunderstood your question, I apologise.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help - this I am doing. The problem is that Phalcon will do a new query each time you access a relationship object. Most of the time, not an issue, but if you loop through 1000 items and access a relationship each loop, you will end up with 1,000 extra queries which is what I was trying to avoid. Hope that helps clarify!